# Certain downloaded files take minutes to become usable

Tags: download, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials, windows-defender

I'm on Windows 8.1 Pro, but this problem also happens on my W7 Premium computer.

I sometimes download files but am unable to use them for 2-3 minutes after they've been downloaded. It happens occasionally with one-off downloads, but I have been able to reproduce it with the Windows executable of [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) (it happens **every single time** I download a new version of the executable from the site). Since I know it happens repeatedly with youtube-dl in Chrome, my main browser, I tried the download in IE and FF, but the issue persists.

I use Windows Defender on my 8.1 computers and MSE on my 7 computer, and I'm guessing that's causing the problem. But why would it take so long to scan a single file that's ~5 MB in size? And why does it only happen with certain files? My desktop isn't top-of-the-line, but it's very fast and has no trouble with gaming, so I don't know why a virus scan would take so long. *(I know gaming is entirely separate, I just mention that as a benchmark of the fact that my computer is NOT old or slow by any means.)*

Comment: Windows 8 has built in protection beyond Windows Defender which is based on the reputation of the file but Windows 7 does not

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that too in Windows 8.1. The Defender seems to take some time to make the virus check. The main bottleneck is probably your disk. If you had a SSD for the OS, it would probably be faster.

Comment: I actually do have an SSD, the problem still occurs when I download to the SSD (downloads normally go to my SSHD, which is also much faster than a normal HDD).